# Ubuntu 2204 installation issue

Tags: drivers, nvidia, asus, window

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 in my personal computer but I am obtaining a bunch of error in every operative system.
-ROG MAXIMUS Z690 HERO BIOS Ver. 0803
-12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) 19-12900KF
-4 DRAM G-Skill 16384MB 4800MHz
-2 NVIDIA GRAPHICS CARDS RTX A6000

First of all, it was disconnected the PC completely from the electricity and it was removed the CMOS battery for 10 minutes.

Ubuntu 22.04:
The process was completed successfully but after the rebooting steps, it is obtained a frozen windows with the error:

1.0248171 i2c i2c-2: Failed to register i2c client ITE8853:00 at 0xte (-16)
I have never seen this error before. I have already checked the available information about this error but it didn’t fixed my problem.

Also, I tried to install UBUNTU 18.04 and Windows 11.

Ubuntu 18.04:
The process was completed successfully, it was not obtained any error but it was NOT detected the wifi adapter. Even, it was reinstalled using the installation with third party drivers but it didn’t fixed the problem

Windows11: The process was completed successfully and the pc was able to use, it was able to use install the NVIDIA drivers but it couldn’t install the driver from the official ASUS website. It was obtained an error:
The driver is not compatible with this version of the operative system.
Even it was tried with the Windows 10 and Windows 11 official drivers.

*Although, I tested Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 11, I would like solving the problem of Ubuntu 22.04.

Could you help me with this? I really need to do my scientific work with this pc. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Thank you for you comment. On the other hand, I am more interested in covering the issue in Ubuntu 22.04. In this Ubuntu version, the wifi adapter is working properly. In any case, let me know if doing the troubleshooting can help to solve the problem